# g++: After Ubuntu distro upgrade, none of my code will link

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++, debian, ld

I am using eclipse CDT for a massive C++ project that has been compiling beautifully for 2 years now. I started having some weird segfaults that made no sense about 2 weeks ago and it appeared that somehow gtk had been corrupted. So since it was about time for a distro upgrade anyways I decided to upgrade from 11.04 to 12.04. Now, nothing will link. Every dependency I have throws an undefined reference error at link time. Everything compiles fine and all of the pkg-config commands are returning what they should.

Any ideas?

Here is the command:

```
  Invoking: GCC C++ Linker g++ `pkg-config libv4l2 --libs` `pkg-config --libs alsa` -lmysqlcppconn -lboost_regex `pkg-config sigc++-2.0 --libs` `pkg-config gstreamer-0.10 --libs` `pkg-config gstreamer-app-0.10 --libs` `pkg-config gstreamer-interfaces-0.10 --libs` `pkg-config gstreamer-rtp-0.10 --libs` `pkg-config glib-2.0 --libs` `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --libs` -lX11 -ldl -lXext  `pkg-config gdkmm-2.4 --libs` `pkg-config glib-2.0 --libs` `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --libs` `pkg-config ptlib --libs` `pkg-config opal --libs` -fexceptions -o"HHPVideoServer"  ./HHPVideoCodec.o ./engine.o  ./opal/GstEndPoint.o ./opal/Linux_GstEndPoint.o ./opal/opal-call-manager.o  ./logging/log.o  ./gui/HHPVideoCodecGui.o ./gui/misc.o  ./framework/services.o  ./StreamEngine/GSTMediaStream.o ./StreamEngine/HHPStreamingEndPoint.o ./StreamEngine/HHPStreamingProtocol.o ./StreamEngine/Linux_GstMediaStream.o  ./SDKEngine/AudioSettings.o ./SDKEngine/CallSettings.o ./SDKEngine/ClientSocket.o ./SDKEngine/Communications.o ./SDKEngine/DeviceInfo.o ./SDKEngine/FileActions.o ./SDKEngine/MediaCodecs.o ./SDKEngine/NetworkSettings.o ./SDKEngine/OSDSettings.o ./SDKEngine/SDKEngine.o ./SDKEngine/SDKEngineCore.o ./SDKEngine/SIPAccount.o ./SDKEngine/ServerSocket.o ./SDKEngine/SessionScheduleDisplay.o ./SDKEngine/Socket.o ./SDKEngine/VideoInput.o  ./DigitalIO/DigitalIOCore.o ./DigitalIO/DigitalInputEngine.o   
./HHPVideoCodec.o: In function `HHPVideoCodec':
/home/jonathan/workspace/HHPVideoServer/Debug/../HHPVideoCodec.cc:9: undefined reference to `PProcess::PProcess(char const*, char const*, unsigned short, unsigned short, PProcess::CodeStatus, unsigned short, bool)'
/home/jonathan/workspace/HHPVideoServer/Debug/../HHPVideoCodec.cc:9: undefined reference to `PTimedMutex::PTimedMutex()'
/home/jonathan/workspace/HHPVideoServer/Debug/../HHPVideoCodec.cc:9: undefined reference to `PTimedMutex::PTimedMutex()'
/home/jonathan/workspace/HHPVideoServer/Debug/../HHPVideoCodec.cc:9: undefined reference to `PTimedMutex::~PTimedMutex()'
/home/jonathan/workspace/HHPVideoServer/Debug/../HHPVideoCodec.cc:9: undefined reference to `PProcess::~PProcess()'....
```

It goes on for thousands of lines, with an undefined reference for every lib.

Comment: Can you compile and link from the command line, without using Eclipse? What about a trivial "hello, world" program? Show us a minimal example and the exact error messages.

Comment: Please copy the exact error message and paste it into your question.  We need to know what the undefined symbol(s) are.  (Also, you could try searching the web for that symbol name - other people may have had the same problem).

Comment: @KeithThompson No, It doesn't work from the command line either. (Eclipse is using a make file anyhow). Also, a trivial program compiles and links fine.

Comment: @user9876 I added the linker command. It is every symbol I have tried from glib to gstreamer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The libraries (as output by pkg-config) should be listed after the .o files.  The order of arguments to the linker matters.

Comment: Ok, that has me down to one bad lib. Why would it work in all of my previous distros and suddenly break now?

Comment: More information on this issue and the reason: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NattyNarwhal/ToolchainTransition